# byte prefix in python string

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I am trying to generate a random string using loremipsum package

```
from loremipsum import generate_paragraph, get_sentences, get_sentence
sentences_count, words_count, paragraph = generate_paragraph()
print(paragraph)
```

It outputs a string with byte prefixes i.e., each word is pre-fixed with a with b or B.

> B'ante' b'ut' b'a' b'ut' b'a'. B'nibh' b'ad' b'in' b'non' b'a' b'dui'
>   b'nunc' b'a'. B'diam' b'at' b'a' b'eros' b'a'. B'quis' b'at' b'a' b'a'
>   b'a' b'a' b'eros' b'a' b'porta'. B'orci' b'id' b'mi' b'ut' b'eleifend'
>   b'fames' b'rutrum' b'at' b'luctus' b'diam'. B'arcu' b'et'. B'pede'
>   b'ut' b'a' b'a'. B'elit' b'at' b'pretium' b'netus' b'amet' b'nunc'.
>   B'nunc' b'eu' b'a' b'mi' b'ultricies' b'ut' b'a' b'etiam' b'quis'.
>   B'nisl' b'mi'. B'orci' b'id' b'a'. B'eget' b'ad' b'a' b'a' b'a' b'ad'
>   b'magna' b'pretium' b'sed'. B'elit' b'eu' b'a' b'congue' b've' b'a'

How can I get rid of these byte prefixes in python 3.6.5.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get rid of the b-prefix in a string in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41918836/how-do-i-get-rid-of-the-b-prefix-in-a-string-in-python)

Comment: This is not a duplicate, but an error in the `loremipsum` libary.

Comment: Indeed completely broken. I am using `python-lorem` from [here](https://github.com/JarryShaw/lorem)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `loremipsum` is broken, because they return a string containing formatted bytes, which makes *zero* sense. To temporarily fix this, you can use this function:

```
import re
from loremipsum import generate_paragraph

def fix_loremipsum(loremipsum_string):
    loremipsum_string = re.sub("B'(.*?)'", lambda x: x.group(1).title(), loremipsum_string)
    loremipsum_string = re.sub("b'(.*?)'", lambda x: x.group(1), loremipsum_string)
    return loremipsum_string


sentences_count, words_count, paragraph = generate_paragraph()
paragraph = fix_loremipsum(paragraph)
print(paragraph)
```

Comment: I have tried this earlier, and getting the following error: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'. I believe this is specific to python 3.x

Comment: I just tried, and found out that the `loremipsum` libary returns a string of formatted bytes. WTF. You should send the coder an email.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
import loremipsum as l
l.generator._DICTIONARY = [i.decode('utf8') for i in l.generator._DICTIONARY]
l._GENERATOR = l.Generator()
print(l.get_paragraph())
```