# reformat output from subprocess.run()

Tags: python, subprocess, output

I'm running python 3.5. After capturing the output from the terminal it appears slightly different in my Python IDE. It's got additional characters I don't need i.e. '\n' or "b''". I tried to use split() and replace() but nothing is working. What am I doing wrong?

```
def runIndexTest(zone):

    print('Turning OFF flit on ' + zone)
    #setIndexStatus(zone, 'stop')

    cmd1 = 'psql -h ' + zone + ' -U filmlight -t -c ' + '"' + """SELECT datname FROM pg_database WHERE datistemplate = false AND datname LIKE """ + "'fsdb%'" + ';"'
    #print(cmd1)

    out = subprocess.run(cmd1, shell=True,
                         stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                         stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    print(out.stdout)

    db_list = str(out.stdout).split(' ')
    for db in db_list:
        db = db.replace("\n", '')
        if db == "b'":
            db_list.remove(db)
            continue

    print('Length of db_list:', len(db_list))
    print(db_list)
```

Output:

```
b' fsdb\n fsdb1\n fsdb_fetish_images$v1\n fsdb_fetish_images\n fsdb_fetish_images$v2\n\n'
Length of db_list: 5
['fsdb\\n', 'fsdb1\\n', 'fsdb_fetish_images$v1\\n', 'fsdb_fetish_images\\n', "fsdb_fetish_images$v2\\n\\n'"]
```

Desired output:

```
['fsdb', 'fsdb1', 'fsdb_fetish_images$v1', 'fsdb_fetish_images', 'fsdb_fetish_images$v2']
```

Comment: Related: [How do I get rid of the b-prefix in a string in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41918836/how-do-i-get-rid-of-the-b-prefix-in-a-string-in-python),

Comment: I think you can use str(your_string_here) function to convert it. But if you use decode("utf-8") it shouldn't appear anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to decode the string:

```
print(out.stdout.decode("utf-8"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension:

```py
db_list = str(out.stdout).split(' ')
db_list = [x.replace("\\n", '') for x in db_list if x!= "b'" ]
```

Answer (score 1):

The `b'...'` is a [bytes literal](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals). To make it a `str` [decode it](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode). The `'\n'`'s are newline characters which are white space use [`str.split()` with the default argument (whitespace)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split).

```
In [9]: s
Out[9]: b' fsdb\n fsdb1\n fsdb_fetish_images$v1\n fsdb_fetish_images\n fsdb_fetish_images$v2\n\n'

In [10]: s.decode('utf-8')
Out[10]: ' fsdb\n fsdb1\n fsdb_fetish_images$v1\n fsdb_fetish_images\n fsdb_fetish_images$v2\n\n'

In [11]: s.decode('utf-8').split()
Out[11]: 
['fsdb',
 'fsdb1',
 'fsdb_fetish_images$v1',
 'fsdb_fetish_images',
 'fsdb_fetish_images$v2']
```