# Is there a way to read secret data using kubernetes library in python?

Tags: python, kubernetes

I want to read the DAYA label value from the kubectl get secret -o wide command shown below.

[image]

I using this code:

```
from kubernetes import client, config
config.load_kube_config()
v1 = client.CoreV1Api()
secret = v1.read_namespaced_secret("mysql-pass", "default")
print(secret)
```

However, the value of the data label was not found...

```
{'api_version': None,
 'data': {'ca.crt': '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',
          'namespace': 'ZGVmYXVsdA==',
          'token': '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'},
 'kind': None,
 'metadata': {'annotations': {'kubernetes.io/service-account.name': 'default',
                              'kubernetes.io/service-account.uid': 'bfde36bb-e67f-420d-ae63-c0e7fd8e750d'},
              'cluster_name': None,
              'creation_timestamp': datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 18, 11, 48, 19, tzinfo=tzutc()),
              'deletion_grace_period_seconds': None,
              'deletion_timestamp': None,
              'finalizers': None,
              'generate_name': None,
              'generation': None,
              'initializers': None,
              'labels': None,
              'managed_fields': [{'api_version': 'v1',
                                  'fields': None,
                                  'manager': 'kube-controller-manager',
                                  'operation': 'Update',
                                  'time': datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 18, 11, 48, 19, tzinfo=tzutc())}],
              'name': 'default-token-zvl8k',
              'namespace': 'default',
              'owner_references': None,
              'resource_version': '319',
              'self_link': '/api/v1/namespaces/default/secrets/default-token-zvl8k',
              'uid': 'd11e5725-7ce5-4a9d-b6fb-4bb76c8fb9eb'},
 'string_data': None,
 'type': 'kubernetes.io/service-account-token'}
```

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question but your `data` labels is right there in the dictionary? With base64 encoded values as you'd expect...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed by user Dandy, there are 2 possible interpretations to this question:

- Getting the `data` field from the `secret` - comment (I thought this first)
- Getting the `DATA` (counter) from the `kubectl get secret -o yaml` - answer

Not really sure why did you post a code sample referencing the secret `mysql-pass` and included the output of the `default-token-zvl8k`

---

I've created an example to show you both options:

`secret.yaml`

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: example-secret
type: Opaque
data:
  username: a3J1awo= # kruk 
  password: c3VwZXJoYXJkcGFzc3dvcmQ= # superhardpassword
```

`Python3` code:

```py
from kubernetes import client, config
import base64

config.load_kube_config()
v1 = client.CoreV1Api()
secret = v1.read_namespaced_secret("example-secret", "default") # get the secret 

data = secret.data # extract .data from the secret 
name = secret.metadata.name
password = secret.data['password'] # extract .data.password from the secret

decoded = base64.b64decode(password) # decode (base64) value from pasw

print ("Secret: " + name)
print("-------------")
print("Here you have the data: ")
print(data)
print("COUNTED DATA: " + str(len(data))) # <- ANSWER FOR THE DATA COUNTER
print("-------------")
print("Here you have the decoded password: ")
print(decoded)
```

With above code you can:

- extract needed information from secret named `example-secret`.
- count the slices from the data field (as in `$ kubectl get secret -o yaml`) - pointed by user Dandy

The output of above `Python3` script:

```sh
Secret: example-secret
-------------
Here you have the data: 
{'password': 'c3VwZXJoYXJkcGFzc3dvcmQ=', 'username': 'a3J1awo='}
COUNTED DATA: 2
-------------
Here you have the decoded password: 
b'superhardpassword'
```

As for `b''` you can look here:

- *[Stackoverflow.com: Questions: How do I get rid of the b prefix in a string in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41918836/how-do-i-get-rid-of-the-b-prefix-in-a-string-in-python)*

Answer (score 1):

There is no "data" / count label. That is a count of the amount of slices found in the `data` array.

So all you'll need to do is count the items in that dict in your response and you'll have the same number.