# Am i doing the .encoode correctly?

Tags: python, encode

So i tried using the .encode on a str, but the encoded message always turned out as b'*str here*'

```
m = 'hello'
t=m.encode(encoding='UTF-8')
print(t)
```

output:

```
b'hello'
```

I've used other people's codes before, and in some way and somehow it works, but when I do the exact same thing, everything the same, but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Did you tried to print `b'hello'[0]` and see the result ?

Comment: im confused on what you mean by that, the output itself is b'hello', if you could please explain a bit more

Comment: To check why appears the b : https://stackoverflow.com/a/6269785/7127519

Comment: See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html#converting-to-bytes)

Comment: To remove the b: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41918864/7127519

Comment: ill check them out