# "await message.channel.send()" code for discord.py giving me syntax error

Tags: python, syntax, discord, discord.py, indentation

I am trying to create a simple bot for a discord server in Python. For now, as a joke, I am just trying to create a "report" command that will send the entire Bee Movie script to whoever types that.
For some reason, whenever I try to do `await message.channel.send(line.strip())` I get an "invalid syntax error"

Does anyone have any tips on how to solve this issue?

```
# bot.py
import os

import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('TOKEN')

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix ='$')

def read_lines(file):
    with open(file, 'rb') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            if line == "\n":
                print("\nEmpty Line\n")
            else:
                await message.channel.send(line.strip())
                return


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{client.user} has connected to Discord!')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
      return

    if message.content.startswith('$hello'):
      await message.channel.send('Hello!')

    if message.content.startswith('$report'):
        read_lines('bot.txt')


client.run(TOKEN)
```

P.S: I am fairly new to Python and the `return` right after the mentioned line is also giving me an indentation block issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you don't specify `message` in `read_lines()` function in `def read_lines(file)` put another argument and make it async like this: `async def read_lines(file, message)` and in `read_lines("bot.txt")` add this message like this: `await read_lines("bot.txt", message)` and see if it works now.
Final code: (Edit also put `from discord.ext import commands` on top)

```py
import os
from discord.ext import commands
import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('TOKEN')

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix ='$')

async def read_lines(file, message):
    with open(file, 'rb') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            if line == "\n":
                print("\nEmpty Line\n")
            else:
                await message.channel.send(line.strip())
                return


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{client.user} has connected to Discord!')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
      return

    if message.content.startswith('$hello'):
      await message.channel.send('Hello!')

    if message.content.startswith('$report'):
        await read_lines('bot.txt', message)


client.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: Oh I see that makes sense. One last thing, do you know how to remove the b' from the message that is being sent to Discord?
Thanks for the help

Comment: As described [here] you have to decode it. In your case instead of `await message.channel.send(line.strip())` use `await message.channel.send(line.strip().decode("utf8"))`

Comment: sorry i didn't put the link: the [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41918836/how-do-i-get-rid-of-the-b-prefix-in-a-string-in-python)

Comment: oh I see it. Thank you so much

Comment: also, what exactly do the async and the await keywords do?

Comment: It is a little bit complicated you can read about it [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html). For you it should mean that everything that needs `await` before it (some discordpy operations) should be inside an `async` function.